# Syncfusion Flutter Cartesian Charts Remove Grey 'Border'

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am using Syncfusion, Flutter Cartesian Charts. I am trying to remove the grey coloured lines circled in black, in the photo. I have set the width of majorGridLines, minorGridLines, majorTickLines, minorTickLines to zero but it still appears. Any ideas on how I could remove them? Ideally, I would only want to show the axes.

[image]

```
Widget _buildGraphs() {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: SfCartesianChart(
        primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
          title: AxisTitle(text: 'x / m'),
          crossesAt: 0,
          interval: 0.5,
          rangePadding: ChartRangePadding.additional,
          majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
          minorGridLines: const MinorGridLines(width: 0),
          majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
          minorTickLines: const MinorTickLines(width: 0),
        ),
        primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          title: AxisTitle(text: 'y / m'),
          crossesAt: 0,
          interval: 0.5,
          rangePadding: ChartRangePadding.additional,
          majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
          minorGridLines: const MinorGridLines(width: 0),
          majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
          minorTickLines: const MinorTickLines(width: 0),
        ),
        series: <CartesianSeries>[
          ScatterSeries<PointCharge, double>(
            dataSource: _pointCharges,
            xValueMapper: (PointCharge data, _) => data.x,
            yValueMapper: (PointCharge data, _) => data.y,
            markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(
              shape: DataMarkerType.circle,
            ),
          ),
          ..._lineGraphDataList.map<CartesianSeries>((seriesData) {
            return LineSeries<LineGraphData, double>(
              dataSource: seriesData,
              xValueMapper: (LineGraphData data, _) => data.x,
              yValueMapper: (LineGraphData data, _) => data.y,
              enableTooltip: false,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ],
        enableAxisAnimation: true,
        zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
          enablePinching: true,
          enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for the most part. However, the grey lines you see might be due to the axis lines. To remove or hide them, you can set the color of the axis lines to transparent using the axisLine property for both primaryXAxis and primaryYAxis.

```
primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
  ...
  axisLine: AxisLine(color: Colors.transparent), // Add this line
  ...
),
primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
  ...
  axisLine: AxisLine(color: Colors.transparent), // Add this line
  ...
),
```

Comment: It removes the axes but not the grey coloured border lines. I am trying to remove the grey coloured border lines circled in black

Comment: Try setting the borderWidth of the plotAreaBorder to 0 in the SfCartesianChart widget:

SfCartesianChart(
  plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,  // This should remove the border
  ...
)

Answer (score 0):

You should set `plotAreaBorderWidth: 0` for this issue.